# Returning an observable with switchMap from service will return it wrapped in Array

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I am working on a project with Angular2 and trying to build a lot of the highly dynamic user interface with RxJS's functionality (and Firebase as backend).

Now take the following scenario:

```
this.af.auth
  .filter(Boolean)
  .switchMap((auth) => this.af.database.object('/usersUid/' + auth.uid));
```

This will check if the user is properly logged in and if so switch to the inner observable in order to get to the stored user information (e.g. admin property etc.)

This works well (with both subscribe() and with async pipe in template).

What confuses me is that when I tried to move the observable to a dedicated service and to retrieve it, it will return the observable "wrapped" in an array.

```
// in original component
let userObservable = this.databaseSrv.getUserObservable(); // the userObservable will be wrapped as an Array and the component logic breaks

// in database-service  
getUserObservable(){
  return this.af.auth
  .filter(Boolean)
  .switchMap((auth) => this.af.database.object('/usersUid/' + auth.uid));
}
```

I have tried different variations with map/flatmap/merge... there is certainly something wrong with the way I return the observable, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Any explanation of this behaviour would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try declare `userObservable` as an object, instead of just declaring `let userObservable`. Arrays are in fact objects, so this could have something to do with your object being ending up as an array.

So try:

```
userObservable:Object = {};
this.userObservable = this.databaseSrv.getUserObservable();
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! It didn't quite work the way you described it, but it got me on the right track. See my answer below. Thank you again. Sadly I can not upvote you yet :-(

Comment: No problem, glad I got you on the right track at least :D

Answer (score 1):

Alright, with AJT_82's help I got the right answer now.

```
getUserObservable(){
  return this.af.auth
  .filter(Boolean)
  .switchMap((auth) => this.af.database.object('/usersUid/' + auth.uid));
}
```

returns an Observable, that could be assigned to

```
userObservable:Object = {};
```

But then I could not run a subscribe() or async on it which seems logical. 
I had tried declaring it before as

```
userObservable: Observable<any>
```

with the same strange result (it returning the observable "wrapped" in an Array). I finally got to the solution by using "as FirebaseObjectObservable like so:

```
   this.userObservable = this.db.getUserAsObjectObservable() as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
   this.userObservable.subscribe(data => console.log('Observable', data));
```

This way the observable returned just fine from the service.

Thank you again!